# Low profile options for insulating cathedral ceiling

Tags: insulation, ceiling

I'm looking to convert an existing screened room into a sun room. Part of that process will be insulating the cathedral ceiling. Unfortunately I don't have a lot of space. Ideally I'd like to get R39 in less than 7 1/4" space. The only option seems to be impermeable spray foam for a hot roof. Any other options?

Comment: Polyiso foam board R-13.1 per inch. 2 layers of 2" with drywall over it...?

Comment: Is insulating atop the roof deck an option? Also, what sort of ground snow loads do you get where you're at?

Comment: Unfortunately insulating on top of the roof isn't an option. I'm in Howard County Maryland an it looks like snowloads are 35psf. I'll check out the Polyiso foam boards.